# Swift's Ternary Conditional Operator returning optional from two non-optional values?

Tags: swift, ternary-operator

I found the results of this code curious

```
 @IBOutlet weak var firstButton: UIButton!
 @IBOutlet weak var secondButton: UIButton!


    func selectButton(_ selectThis: UIButton) {
        var deselectThis = (selectThis == firstButton) ? secondButton : firstButton
        setButtonSelectionColor(deselectThis, selectIt: false)
    }
```

The call to setButtonSelectionColor(deselectThis) produces the compile error "Value of optional type 'UIButton?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?".

I'm guessing this has something to do with how firstButton and secondButton are declared, specifically that they are @IBOutlets (still have same compile error if they are defined as weak), but the reason is escaping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@IBOutlet`s are defined as implicitly unwrapped optionals - that's what the `!` stands for at the end of the type. It still is an optional, but you don't have to explicitly unwrap it when used. You could kind of think about this as a promise to the compiler that although this value could be `nil` at some point, you will use it responsibly and only after it has been set. When inferring the type for `deselectThis`, the compiler correctly set it `Optional<UIButton>`, just without the `!` (since `!` doesn't change the type per-se in this case).

You can either wrap the whole expression in an `if let` statement or simply provide the explicitly unwrapped typing by doing `var deselectThis: UIButton! = ...`.

Please note that implicitly unwrapped optionals should be used with care and caution. As always - [more in the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html).

Comment: "are defined as explicitly unwrapped optionals" you mean "Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals"

Comment: You are right, I must have mistyped. Thanks @vacawama for the edit!